# How can I take advantage of the afflictions?

Tags: pandemic-2

In Pandemic 2 sometimes it shows that a country have some problems

[image]

What could I do to take advantage of the situation?

Comment: pretty sure droughts in area means if you use dehydrating related symptoms it'll kill faster, not sure about the others

Answer (score 2):

From the [game guide](http://www.crazymonkeygames.com/guide/Pandemic-2/):

> - Earthquakes greatly reduce the effectiveness of hospitals in the region.
> - Floods temporarily boost exposure to your disease if your disease is able to spread via water.
> - Hurricanes temporarily close airports due to high winds. Also temporarily closes schools and transit.
> - Droughts increase insect population, and boosts exposure to your disease if it is spreadable by insects.
> - Riots negate the effects of curfews.

So to take advantage of these:
1) If a lot of locations are being flooded, and your disease isn't waterbourne, buy that.
2) If a lot of locations are experiencing droughts, make your disease spreadable through insects.
There's not any way to take advantage of the other afflictions.